# Flash AS3: Getting this error: Access of undefined property - basic scope help needed :(

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scope, trace, coercion

I'm still used to the AS2 style of all code on 1 frame, I'm trying to code AS3 in class files and I'm having a problem with a basic package setup. Scope issues are killing me with trying to learn AS3. Below is my package code, I don't have any other class files, just trying to return a simple trace.

The error I'm getting after I run the code below: **1120: Access of undefined property tc.**

---

### Main Class

```
package 
{
    import src.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    // Custom imports to go here
    import src.tradeclass.TradeFrame;   

    public class TraceClass extends MovieClip
    {
        public var tc:TradeFrame;

        public function TraceClass(traceText:String):void
        {
            // Constructor function
        }

    }

    tc = new TradeFrame("hello");
    //TraceClass.TradeFrame("hello");

}
```

---

### Sub Class

```
package src.traceclass 
{
    import src.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class TradeFrame extends MovieClip
    {

        public function TradeFrame(traceText:String):void
        {
            // Constructor function
            trace(traceText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Class needs to be:

```
package src 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;

// Custom imports to go here
import src.tradeclass.TradeFrame;       

public class TraceClass extends MovieClip
{
        public var tc:TradeFrame;

        public function TraceClass(traceText:String = "default text"):void
        {
                // Constructor function
              tc = new TradeFrame("hello");

        }

}
```

Sub Class needs to be:

```
package src.tradeclass {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class TradeFrame extends MovieClip
{

        public function TradeFrame(traceText:String):void
        {
                // Constructor function
                trace(traceText);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a contructor like that. You'll need to do something like:

```
var tc = new TraceClass("hello");
```

EDIT: (after re-reading) Or, try TraceClass.TraceClass("hello");

Comment: Hi Michael, thx for the reply... I tried both ways (the var I forgot about) but now I'm getting a "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method TraceClass through a reference with static type Class."

Comment: I think one of the main problems is that you're defining a class in a package, then trying to test that class in the same package, and I don't _think_ that's possible (not positive, though). I would try setting up a "main" class for testing, create a new instance of the TraceClass in it, and then try to test it via 'new' and then tc.TraceClass("hello");.

Comment: Ah, that's it thanks :) I'll edit my code once I get it working.

Comment: Now I'm getting "1120: Access of undefined property tc"  :( Scope = my.pain

Comment: Ah I Got it working! removed the variable from the main class function and moved "tc = new TradeFrame("hello");" into the main class and it works now. Thx for the help...